# Standard deviation in a non normal distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, standard-deviation, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two datasets, dataset A with 5-10 values and dataset B with around 20 values.
Both are **non** normally distributed and right skewed.

1. Can I use standard deviation to compare the elements internally of a dataset, for instance by calculating the mean of all elements and then calculating the standard deviance for each element?
2. What statistical test should I use to test if there's a significant difference between the two datasets mean? Wilcoxon rank-sum test?

Comment: What do you mean to determine if there is a significant difference between the datasets?  Are you interested in a particular variable?  All variables?  Are you interested in mean differences, or differences in variability or some other measure?

Comment: Hey sorry, updated the question! I'm interested in the mean difference

Comment: If you are interested in comparing the means of two (data sets?) samples, then a t-test would be the first choice. If the assumptions of the t-test are not met (for ex. non-normal residual distribution) then a Mann-Whitney U test can be used.